# Is it safe to copy the bytes of an object out to an array and back again

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it safe to copy the bytes of an object out to an array of `unsigned char` and then back again using `memcpy`, and does it leave the object unchanged?

That is, is the following safe for any `t`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void copy_back_and_forth(T& t) {
  unsigned char buf[sizeof(T)];
  std::memcpy(buf, &t, sizeof(T));
  std::memcpy(&t, buf, sizeof(T));
}
```

... and does it leave `t` unchanged?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Any attachment to `unsigned char` vs [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)?

Comment: @Tas - well, yes in the sense that I am certainly interested if the answer would vary between them.

Comment: @sshashank124 - well it might be obvious to you, but for e.g. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) certainly doesn't make it clear: they say `If the objects are potentially-overlapping or not TriviallyCopyable, the behavior of memcpy is not specified and may be undefined.` ... and link back to SO.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to sound condescending. Just wanted to fill the min-character requirement. Yes it should be the same. Looking at your specific case where you were allocating a separate buffer, it should function correctly

Comment: @sshashank124, ah got it....... :) I agree in practice, but I'm looking from a guarantee from the standard.

Answer (score 6):

The value of `t` is guaranteed to be unchanged if `T` is trivially copyable type, and `t` is not a potentially-overlapping subobject. Standard quote from latest draft:

> [basic.types]
>
> For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of
>   trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid
>   value of type T, the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up the
>   object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or
>   std​::​byte ([cstddef.syn]).<sup>37</sup> If the content of that array is copied
>   back into the object, the object shall subsequently hold its original
>   value.
>
> 37) By using, for example, the library functions ([headers]) std​::​memcpy or std​::​memmove.

In fact, the standard has a nearly identical example:

> [ Example:
>
> ```
> constexpr std::size_t N = sizeof(T);
> char buf[N];
> T obj;                          // obj initialized to its original value
> std::memcpy(buf, &obj, N);      // between these two calls to std​::​memcpy, obj might be modified
> std::memcpy(&obj, buf, N);      // at this point, each subobject of obj of scalar type holds its original value
> ```
>
> — end example  ]

Comment: Right, that's the general condition for `memcpy` to be safe, even if object is modified between the calls. I'm interested in the special case where the calls are back-to-back and wondering if this loosens the conditions. In particular, although the exactly from the standard looks very similar, the comment "obj might be modified" is very relevant.

Comment: @BeeOnRope Also relevant is "between these calls". After the second memcpy, the object is guaranteed to have been modified back to the original value. I suppose that this implies that the operation is not guaranteed to be thread safe.